# BitTorrent client implementation – Peer ignoring requests

Tags: tcp, elixir, bittorrent

I am implementing a bittorrent client to learn that protocol and practice code, in Elixir.

I am testing my client with Transmission as a seed on a local tracker.

I can successfully handshake Transmission, receive its bitfield (full) and send mine (all zeros) and send the "interested" message, and Transmission unchokes me.

Then I am sending those two chunk requests:

```
<<6, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 64, 0>> # index: 2, begin: 0,     length: 16384
<<6, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 64, 0, 0, 0, 64, 0>> # index: 2, begin: 16384, length: 16384
```

Edit: in hex that is (again without the length prefix on four bytes):

```
06 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00
06 00 00 00 02 00 00 40 00 00 00 40 00
```

I am not showing the length prefix as it is handled automatically by the  T̶C̶P̶ ̶l̶a̶y̶e̶r̶ `gen_tcp` library configured with `{packet, 4}` except for the handshake where it is just `19`. It works for all other messages.

To me it looks fine: `6` on one byte, then the piece index (`2` here) on four bytes, and the offset and length on four bytes each.

In the Transmission peers view, I can see myself, with no requests, and the `?I` flags where `?` means that I am not choked (true) and not interested (false, as I send the "interested" message which is just `<<2>>` (and the length prefix)).

Can you spot anything that I am doing wrong? Or maybe I skipped a step?

After sending those two requests nothing happens, then I receive like four keepalive empty messages from Transmission and finally Transmission closes the connection.

Thank you.

PS: I saw another question here but it was because the chunk size were not proper. Here my torrent is `161920` bytes long and the piece length is `32768`. It's a single file.

Comment: The TCP layer does not handle length, you need to include those on the application level because on the application level TCP is a stream of bytes, not of demarcated messages.

Comment: @the8472 hi, thank you, sorry I meant the TCP library for erlang using `packet` option to automatically handle prefixes except for the handshake. https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html#setopts-2 It is at the application layer indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any issue. A common way of debugging bittorrent clients is using wireshark which has a protocol dissector for bittorrent which works as long as the TCP connection has been captured from the beginning. With that you can see what actually goes over the wire. For comparison you could also look at two working bittorrent clients talking to each other (although they're likely to use some extensions on top of the vanilla BEP3 protocol).

Transmission sending keep-alives suggests that it didn't run into a protocol violation that would result in an immediate disconnect and instead is still waiting on something.

Comment: Thank you, I did not use wireshark but I managed to intrument another bittorrent client to dump exactly what was sent/received and when, and found a race condtion. I'll accept this answer because monitoring the communications is important and wireshark could help someone else ending up there.